# What is minimum degree of a regular graph with given diameter and number of vertices?

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory, combinations, extremal-combinatorics

Suppose we need to have a regular graph with ${2^n}$ vertices and diameter $O((\log n)^c)$ at some $c\geq 1$ what should its minimal degree be?

Answer (score 1):

Let's say that $G$ is a regular graph of degree $d$ and diameter $\gamma$. Fix your favorite vertex $v$ and let $N_i(v)=\{u\in V:\text{dist}(v,u)=i\}$. Since $G$ is regular of degree $d$, we have $N_1(v)=d$ and $|N_i(v)|\leq(d-1)|N_{i-1}(v)|$ for all $i\geq 2$. Furthermore, since $G$ has diameter $\gamma$, we have $V=\bigcup_{i=0}^\gamma N_i(v)$. Therefore,
$$
|V|=\sum_{i=0}^\gamma |N_i(v)|\leq 1+d\sum_{i=0}^{\gamma-1}(d-1)^i=1+d{(d-1)^\gamma-1\over d-2}\leq d^\gamma,
$$
for $\gamma\geq 2$ and $d\geq 3$.
Now, $|V|=2^n$ and $\gamma=O(\log^c n)$, so we must have $2^n\leq d^{O(\log^c n)}$, or in other words $n\leq O(\log^c n\cdot \log d)$. Solving this, we must have $d\geq 2^{\Omega(n/\log^c n)}$.